# iOS swift pointer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
CGPoint startPoint1;
CGPoint startPoint2;
CGPoint startPoint3;
CGPoint startPoint4;

- (void)Method {
    CGPoint* startPoint = NULL;

    if (panGesture.view == ...) {
       startPoint = &startPoint1;
    } else if (panGesture.view == ...) {
       startPoint = &startPoint2;
    }

    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       *startPoint = [panGesture locationInView:...]
    } else if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
       CGPoint endPoint = [panGesture locationInView:...];
       *startPoint = endPoint;
    }
}

CGPoint* startPoint = NULL;
startPoint = &startPoint1;
*startPoint = endPoint;
```

This three lines of code in Swift 3.0 is how to express Or how do I write the above code into swift

Comment: You can't treat struct(CGPoint) as class. Struct doesn't support pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swift, I would use enums and an array. I simplified the code a litte, but I guess you'll get it:

```
var points = [CGPoint(), CGPoint()]
enum indexEnum:Int {
    case startPoint = 0
    case endPoint   = 1
}

func method() {
    var inx:indexEnum

    if (1==1) {
        inx = .startPoint
    } else {
        inx = .endPoint
    }

    if (2==2) {
        points[inx.rawValue] = CGPoint(x:10,y:10)
    } else {
        points[inx.rawValue] = CGPoint(x:20,y:20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved my question according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Swift doesn't have pointers in the C sense. Well, it does, sort of, but it's not worth invoking them just to do what you're trying to do. The simplest approach is to rewrite the core of your method to call a function that takes an `inout` parameter.

So let's take the reduction you ask about in your last three lines:

```
CGPoint* startPoint = NULL;
startPoint = &startPoint1;
*startPoint = endPoint;
```

To do that, we need a general way to set one CGPoint to another by indirection, expressed as a `func` (because that is the only way to work with an `inout` parameter). To make it truly general, we may as well make this a generic, so we're not confined to CGPoint alone:

```
func setByIndirection<T>(_ thing1 : inout T, to thing2: T) {
    thing1 = thing2
}
```

And now we can test it, doing exactly what you asked to do:

```
var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
let endPoint = CGPoint(x:5, y:5)
setByIndirection(&startPoint, to: endPoint)
print(startPoint) // 5,5
```

So you see, the use of the `inout` parameter has allowed us to pass into the function a "pointer" to the CGPoint whose value is to be set, which is what your code is trying to accomplish at its heart.

If you're willing to "damage" your original `endPoint`, you don't even need to write `setByIndirection`; you can use the built-in `swap`:

```
var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
var endPoint = CGPoint(x:5, y:5)
swap(&startPoint, &endPoint)
```

Comment: No problem. I agree with Andreas that it is better not to do _at all_ in Swift what you were doing, but I wanted to show you how it _could_ be done if you really had to.